# How can I show all permutations in python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I want to all the outcome as follows:

Permutations of 'abc': '', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ba', 'ac', 'ca', 'bc', 'cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba'

Thank for your help.

Comment: Downvoted because this has been answered many times on Stackoverflow.

Comment: -1 because I find it really strange that you know about Stack Overflow but not Google.

Answer (score 4):

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

["".join(perm) for perm in chain.from_iterable(permutations("abc", n) for n in range(4))]
#>>> ['', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

The `permutations("abc", n)` gives all permutations of length `n`, I get that for all `n` from `0...3`, chain them together and then `"".join` each item.